# Why does my variable return null instead of the defined value

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know why my **"Carry"** variable in the code returns NAN instead of 0

```js
var addBinary = function(a, b) {
  let i = a.length - 1
  let j = b.length - 1

  let result = []
  var carry = 0;
  while (i >= 0 || j >= 0) {
    if (i == 0) {
      console.log(carry)
    }

    let sum = carry

    if (i >= 0) {
      sum = sum + parseInt(a[i])
    }

    if (j >= 0) {
      sum += parseInt(b[i])
    }

    result.unshift(parseInt(sum) % 2)
    carry = parseInt(sum) / 2
    i--
    j--
  }

  if (carry > 0) {
    result.unshift(1)
  }
  // console.log(result)
  return result.toString()
};

addBinary('11', '1')
```

console.log(carry) should return 0 and not NAN. I can't seem to find the issue, sure I am missing something

Comment: `abbBinary` is a typo for `addBinary`

Comment: At one point you're trying to access `b[1]` which is undefined (because `b.length` is 1). You have to loop through both strings separately.

Comment: Typo: `b[i]` should be `b[j]`.

Comment: `if (j >= 0) {  sum += parseInt(b[i]) }` did you mean `b[j]`?

Comment: simple console.log() statements would clear up why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason console.log(carry) returns Nan is because you wrote: carry = parseInt(sum) / 2;
This redefines carry to Nan instead of 0 (first time you go through the while loop carry is 0, but second time it is Nan). parseInt(sum) returns null (Nan), because at another point you wrote b[i] instead of b[j].

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var addBinary = function(a, b) {
  let i = a.length - 1
  let j = b.length - 1
  
  let result = []
  var carry = 0;
  while(i >= 0 || j >= 0){
        if(i == 0){
          console.log(carry)
      }
      
       let sum = carry
       
     
      if(i >= 0){
          sum = sum + parseInt(a[i])
      }
      
       
      
      if(j >= 0){
          
          sum += parseInt(b[i])
      }
      
     
      result.unshift(parseInt(sum)%2)
      
      carry = parseInt(sum)/2
      i--
      j--
  }
  
  if(carry > 0){
      result.unshift(1)
  }
  console.log(carry);
  // console.log(result)
  return result.toString();
};


    addBinary('11','1'); // output NaN
    addBinary(11,1); // as we are passing numbers no quotes are needed expected output 0
```